# My wife wants another baby but we are already grandparents! Help!

Tags: communication, family-planning

My wife wants another child. We have 9 already between us. Our oldest is 23 and youngest just turned 2. Our oldest made us grandparents in April and just found out that she's expecting again. I am going to be 63 when the youngest graduates high school. We each had 3 when we met and have 3 between us. Ages for all kids are 23, 22, 20,19, 17, 16, 7, 4, and 2.
Help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the topics listed [here](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You just say "help" but what is your actual question to us that you want us to answer?

Answer (score 9):

Having or not having children is an individual decision which should not be forced on another person; that is, you have a right (and likely many good reasons) to refuse to have any more children, and your wife has a right to continue having children - but not with you.

Clearly that's a drastic solution that I do not recommend. You have children and grandchildren between you, and to separate would be tragic for so many people. But your wife cannot *force* you to have more children, any more than you should be able to force her to have children against her will.

I can't imagine that you haven't talked about this. If you cannot work this out between yourselves, you should seek counseling to try to discover why it is so important for your wife to continue childbearing and child rearing, and what can be done about it. There is something driving your wife's desire, and it should be dealt with straightforwardly (with help).